# Is a revision required to the "What topics can I ask about here?" page in the Help Center?

Tags: discussion

In the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page it clearly states that:

> Ask Different is for **users of Apple products**. If you have a
>   question about ...
>
> - Apple hardware
> - Apple software
> - Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)
> - third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products.
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Recently [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) corrected me because I had assumed a question about a formula in Excel was off-topic. I accepted his correction (obviously, as a moderator with the highest reputation I wasn't going to think he was wrong!), but since then I've seen a number of instances where users have voted to close questions as off-topic because the questions were about third-party software.

This got me to thinking that perhaps the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page could do with some minor revision. It may be something as simple as a formatting change to bold the words "third-party hardware, services and software" in the last bullet point.

What do others think?

Comment: Whiuch questions were closed - I would also not the off topic condition - Basic Customer Support - so can be a matter of opinion which of the two criteria apply.

Comment: I'm not sure the questions were actually closed, just that there were people voting for them to be closed. But I do agree that it often comes down to a matter of opinion in terms of what category applies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, somebody using Excel on macOS **is** a user of an Apple product, and the bullet list makes it rather clear what a question can be about. I partially understand your confusion, but IMHO the wording is rather clear.

Comment: I agree the wording **is** clear, but in the past week I've seen a few questions users have voted to close on the basis they were off-topic when, based on the last bullet point, they aren't. I think the last bullet point is a little lost, not only because it's the last one, but because the first three start with the word _Apple_ which stands out because it's 'Apple' and because of the capital 'A'. Also, the stem sentence has _users of Apple products_ in **bold**. I guess others will learn that these questions are on-topic, but I just thought a minor formatting change may reduce confusion.

Comment: Yeah, but then we would kind of need all bullets in bold, somehow.